# PyQt5 Pass user inputs from GUI to main code

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have an interface that prompts users for 3 inputs and a selection from a comboBox.  What I want to happen is have all of the information entered by the user, they press the button and then those inputs are used to run on the subsequent processes for the project (folder creation, copying, ect).

My problem is that I do not know how to grab the variable I am assigning from the user inputs.  If I place the app.exec_() after I am calling the variables in if___name___ they appear to never be assigned.   How can call this .py file and pass the necessary inputs to the other parts of my code?  Thanks for any help, I am brand new to python and qt so if this is making no sense ill try my best to clarify...

```
from new2 import Ui_Line
import nextProcess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import glob, os, shutil


    #GUI Called from 'new2' now apply functions to create the line based on users inputs
class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Line):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
      QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
      self.setupUi(self)                            
      self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.assign)      


#Function that happens when the 'click line' button is pressed
    def assign(self): 
      num1  = str(self.num1EDIT.toPlainText())
      num2 = str(self.num2EDIT.toPlainText())
      num3 = str(self.num3EDIT.toPlainText())
      mas = str(self.comboBox.currentText())

      if mas == 'Path 1':
          master = 'cbm' 
      elif mas == 'Path 2':
          master = 'crwt' 
      else:
          master = 'wst'

      #QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit() 
      """Potential fix edit
      proc2 = nextProcess()  <----  Do I need to put nextProcess inside the assign() or in the window()?
      """
      return num1, num2, num3, master

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newWindow = window(None)
    newWindow.show()
    app.exec_()  # <---- This is my fix, but I know this probably isn't correct 
    info = newWindow.assign()
    num1 = info[0]
    num2 = info[1]
    num3 = info[2]
    master = info[3]
    next = nextProcess(num1, num2, num3, master)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the slot connected to the push button's `clicked()` signal quit the application, just have it run the code you're interested in using the appropriate values.

So the `assign()` method could more aptly be named `callNextProcess()`, which retrieves the values from the widgets and just calls `nextProcess()` directly.

Comment: Do I need to pass nextProcess in the class 'window()' or in the function assign?  I am kinda lost on how to call it.

Comment: Usually, the method would be a member of the class itself. You have access to the class instance in the `self` variable, and can then get access to the text fields and their values from that. But if all you need is the numbers (`num1` etc.) that you have here, then `nextProcess()` doesn't need to be a member method. It seems from your code that either way is fine.